# How can I determine 'Network Discovery' status, (enabled|disabled), of a remote computer

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-firewall

I know I can enable it like this:

netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Network Discovery" new enable=Yes

Or disable it like this:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Network Discovery" new enable=No
```

But in my situation, *and this is the important part*, I do not want to just Enable or Disable it, I just need to check its status, (on or off).

I tried to use `show rule` in `netsh` like this:

```
netsh advdirewall firewall show rule="all" | find "Network Discovery"
```

This shows me that there is like `50` different rules containing the name `Network Discovery`, such as `Network Discovery (Pub WSD-Out)` & `Network Discovery (WSD Evebts-Out)`. All of which get changed when the above `set rule group="Network Discovery"` is used. So I have no idea which of those `50` rules is the one presently being in use and therefore cannot see how I can use `show rule` to check if its current status.

If I could find a way to check what rule name is in current use, I could then use`netsh show rule`

So is there a way to find that? or some better way to check if `Network Discovery` or `File and Printer Sharing` is on or off.

Comment: I have come across this same scenario and was hoping we had a pure batch solution in order to suss this out.

Did you ever come across a way to do what you needed without installing a new version of PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

One easy option is via PowerShell directly - or via PowerShell called from CMD, you can run:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "File and Printer Sharing"
```

or

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Network Discovery"
```

You can then use PowerShell cmdlet and output filtering to search for what you are looking for specifically. For example:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Network Discovery" -Enabled True -Action Allow -Direction Inbound
```

To run the command from CMD, you can do this:

```
powershell -command "Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup 'Network Discovery' -Enabled True -Action Allow -Direction Inbound"
```

Also, for future reference, server management questions like this can also be asked on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com)

Comment: I don't know much about powershell, but a lot of the machines that I may be using this on can be anywhere from 1 to 12 year old machines, which is why I needed to keep it simple. Will this work on older versions of windows without installing anything?

I'm guessing not because just trying it on my own Win7 Machine it does not work saying "'Get-NetFirewallRule' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Comment: Correct - this cmdlet was introduced in Win8/Svr 2012 so it would not work on older computers. You can try something like `(New-object -comObject HNetCfg.FwPolicy2).rules | select name,direction,action | select-string "File and Printer Sharing" | select-string "Direction=1" | select-string "Action=1"` -- However, ultimately they are going to show roughly the same thing. The idea being that they retrieve the relevant rules in the group you are querying. *similar to providing multiple piped `find` or `findstr` to netsh advfirewall.